# Stop sound not working in three js?

Tags: audio, three.js

I'm a little bit frustrated that I can't stop a sound. I used the example code on how to play a sound in three js, and under play(), I want to stop to test. It doesn't matter when I stop a sound in gameplay, I get the same error:

TypeError: Not enough arguments

I didn't think calling stop() required any arguments. I am running on Safari and Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

// instantiate a listener
    var audioListener = new THREE.AudioListener();

```
// add the listener to the camera
camera.add( audioListener );

// instantiate audio object
var oceanAmbientSound = new THREE.Audio( audioListener );

// add the audio object to the scene
scene.add( oceanAmbientSound );

// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.AudioLoader();

// load a resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'sounds/mySound.mp3',
    // Function when resource is loaded
    function ( audioBuffer ) {
        // set the audio object buffer to the loaded object
        oceanAmbientSound.setBuffer( audioBuffer );

        // play the audio
        oceanAmbientSound.play();
        oceanAmbientSound.stop();
    },
    // Function called when download progresses
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },
    // Function called when download errors
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's about the `.stop()` method? it [works](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/tp9czrmx/) totally fine without any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out- it must be my old version of Safari (8.0.8). Nonetheless, thanks for your help!